# How can i color the points in the paint event faster?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

This is the code .
But it's not coloring the bmp4 in yellow.
Maybe i did something wrong with the test variable and bmp4 variable and the CreateNonIndexedImage method ?
Tried also to save the bmp4 but it's not working.

In form1 when the operation end i'm saving the bitmap like this:

```
CloudEnteringAlert.test.Save(@"c:\temp\yellowbmpcolor.jpg");
```

But the area that supposed to be in yellow is not it's justl ike the original image.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using DannyGeneral;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;



namespace mws
{
    public static class CloudEnteringAlert
    {



        private static PointF point1;
        private static PointF point2;
        public static float redlinerectx1= 0;
        public static float redlinerecty1 = 0;
        public static float redlinerectx = 0;
        public static float redlinerecty = 0;
        private static Bitmap bm;
        private static Bitmap bmp2 = new Bitmap(@"C:\Temp\New folder (17)\radar001486.GIF");
        public static Bitmap test = new Bitmap(@"D:\MyWeatherStation-Images-And-Icons\radar090.PNG");
        public static Bitmap bmp4 = CreateNonIndexedImage(test);
        static BitmapData b1 = bmp4.LockBits(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, bmp4.Width, bmp4.Height),
                             System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadWrite,
                             System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

        static int stride = b1.Stride;
        static int k1, x1, y1;
        static float fx, fy;
        static System.IntPtr Scan0 = b1.Scan0;
        public static List<string> pointscoordinates = new List<string>();
        public static float radius = 2.0f;
        private static Label lbl1 = new Label();
        public static bool cloudsfound;
        // blinking colors: yellow, red, yellow, transparent, repeat...
        public static Brush[] cloudColors = new[] { Brushes.Yellow, Brushes.Transparent };
        // current color index
        public static int cloudColorIndex = 0;
        public static List<PointF> AddDistanceToPoints = new List<PointF>();
        public static List<PointF> MovingPoints = new List<PointF>();
        public static List<PointF> PointsFloat = new List<PointF>();
        public static List<Point> PointsInt;
        public static List<PointF> pointtocolor = new List<PointF>();
        public static List<PointF> extendedPoints = new List<PointF>();
        public static Bitmap newbitmap;
        private static List<PointF> clouds1;
        public static List<PointF> clouds;
        public static List<PointF> cloudsG = new List<PointF>();
        public static List<PointF> cloudsY;
        public static List<PointF> cloudsR;
        private static Bitmap bmp3;
        private static  int tolerancenumeric = 0;
        private static double[] treshhold_array = { 100, 50, 40, 30, 24, 18, 13, 9, 6, 4, 2, 1.2, 0.7, 0.2, 0.1 };
        static List<float> LoadPoints_X = new List<float>();
        static List<float> LoadPoints_Y = new List<float>();
        static List<float> points_X = new List<float>();
        static List<float> points_Y = new List<float>();
        static string path;
        static string file;
        static List<PointF> points;

        public static Bitmap CreateNonIndexedImage(Image src)
        {
            Bitmap newBmp = new Bitmap(src.Width, src.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

            using (Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage(newBmp))
            {
                gfx.DrawImage(src, 0, 0);
            }

            return newBmp;
        }

        static CloudEnteringAlert()
        {
            points = new List<PointF>();
            cloudsfound = false;
        }

        public static void Paint(Graphics e, double currentFactor, float kilometers)
        {
            Pen myPen = new Pen(Brushes.Red, 2);
            float x, y ,width, height;
            float distance = kilometers / (float)1.09;//289617486; // One pixel distance is 1.09 kilometer.

            if (points == null)
            {
                return;
            }

             redlinerectx = MovingPoints[0].X;
             redlinerecty = MovingPoints[0].Y;

             if (clouds != null)
             {
                 y = PointsInt.Min(p => p.Y);
                 PointF pointsIntMin = PointsInt.First(p => p.Y == y); //point with minimum Y in PointsInt list
                 y = PointsInt.Max(p => p.Y);
                 PointF pointsIntMax = PointsInt.First(p => p.Y == y); //point with maximum Y in PointsInt list

                 y = MovingPoints.Min(p => p.Y);
                 PointF movingPointsMin = MovingPoints.First(p => p.Y == y); //point with minimum Y in MovingPoints list
                 y = MovingPoints.Max(p => p.Y);
                 PointF movingPointsMax = PointsInt.First(p => p.Y == y); //point with minimum Y in MovingPoints list

                 x = pointsIntMin.X * (float)currentFactor;
                 y = pointsIntMin.Y * (float)currentFactor;
                 width = movingPointsMin.X + distance - x;
                 height = (pointsIntMax.Y - pointsIntMin.Y) * (float)currentFactor;

                 if (clouds != null)
                 {
                     e.DrawRectangle(myPen, (int)x, (int)y, (int)width, (int)height);
                 }

                 myPen.Dispose();

                 try
                 {
                     unsafe
                     {
                         byte* p;

                         for (k1 = 0; k1 < pointtocolor.Count; k1++)
                         {
                             //set pointer to the beggining
                             p = (byte*)(void*)Scan0;
                             fx = pointtocolor[k1].X * (float)currentFactor;
                             fy = pointtocolor[k1].Y * (float)currentFactor;
                             //check if point is inside bmp
                             if ((int)fx >= bmp.Width || (int)fy >= bmp.Height)
                             {
                                 continue;
                             }
                             //Add offset where the point is. The formula: position = Y * stride + X * 4 
                             x = (int)(fy * (float)stride);
                             y = (int)(fx * 4F);

                             p += (x1 + y1);

                             //set yellow color
                             p[1] = p[2] = (byte)255;
                             p[0] = (byte)0;
                             p[3] = (byte)255;
                         }
                     }

                     bmp.UnlockBits(b1);

                 }
                 catch
                 {
                     string t = "err";
                 }
             }
        }
```

EDIT

It is working but the color is not the yellow i need:
This is what i get:

[image: Yellow]

And when i used with SetPixel this is what i got and what i want to get now too:

[image: The yellow i need]

Comment: With a radius of 2f why go for FillEllipse in the first place?

Comment: As TaW said. Maybe it would be more reasonable to use `FillRectangle`, for example? And yes, `SetPixel` is very slow, and it always has been. You can get around this in many ways, for example by doing all the work in a `byte[]` or `uint[]` and then creating the `Bitmap` on top of that data.

Comment: No, that's not what I meant. I would go for lockbits and simply paint those pixels that make up a 2f size circle, probably 5 full color and 4 mixed colors on the corners at most, maybe only 4 in total.. that way all that happens is in the fast lockbits domain.. But of course one may as well mix the two domains by doing the two paint operations __after__ another (not interwoven!): first draw thos ellipses and then go to lockbits for the single pixels..

Answer (score 0):

Draw individual pixels from list with yellow color on *bmp Bitmap*:

```
BitmapData b1 = bmp.LockBits(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height),  
                             System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadWrite,
                             System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

int stride = b1.Stride;
int k, x, y;
float fx, fy;
System.IntPtr Scan0 = b1.Scan0;

unsafe
{
    byte* p;

    for (k = 0; k < pointtocolor.Count; k++)
    {
        //set pointer to the beggining
        p = (byte*)(void*)Scan0;
        fx = pointtocolor[k].X * (float)currentFactor;
        fy = pointtocolor[k].Y * (float)currentFactor;
        //check if point is inside bmp
        if( (int)fx >= bmp.Width || (int)fy >= bmp.Height)
        {
            continue;
        }             
        //Add offset where the point is. The formula: position = Y * stride + X * 4 
        x = (int)fy * stride;
        y = (int)fx * 4;

        p += ( x + y );

        //set yellow color
        p[1] = p[2] = (byte)255;
        p[0] = (byte)0;
        p[3] = (byte)255;
    }
}

bmp.UnlockBits(b1);
```

Comment: On this line i'm getting error: p += ( x + y ); Error 34 Cannot implicitly convert type 'float' to 'byte*' and Error 33 Operator '+=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'byte*' and 'float'

Comment: And on this part: 4F) i'm getting error: Error 29 Invalid expression term ')' and Error 32 Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

Comment: Still the two errors exist on the line: p += (x + y); Can't applied += for byte and float

Comment: γηράσκω δ' αεί πολλά διδασκόμε can you look at my code in my question. Maybe i did something wrong. I used hte unsafe like you did in the Paint method(this paint method i called from form1 paint event). But in the end when i'm saving the image to the hard disk i don't see the specific area in yellow. It looks like just the original image. I'm not getting any errors it's just not in yellow.

Comment: I updated my question with the code is with the problem it's not the whole code only what connected to this problem with the ocloring in yellow.

Comment: @JamesAharon Use **ALL code** as it is in *Paint()*. Dont declare the variables outside *Paint()*. The lock unlock **must** be in *Paint()*

Comment: @JamesAharon There is no *bmp* bitmap in your code. Change *bmp* with the bitmap you want to lock unlock. Declare as *public static* only those that need to be public!

Comment: @JamesAharon It is not **p += ( x1 + y1 );** but **p += ( x + y );**

Comment: @JamesAharon Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61995/discussion-between------and-james-aharon).